# Django form validation clean methods not working

Tags: django, forms, validation, django-forms, django-validation

This is my form class

```
class Feedback(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(validators=[name_validate])
    rollno = forms.IntegerField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    feedback = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

views.py

This is clean method

```
def clean_name(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['name']
    print(len(data))
    if len(data)<4:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Exception')
    return data
```

The control is entering to if condition but not raising error

Comment: You won't notice any raised errors. It is caught by the form and added to form.errors so that you can display to the user how the input is wrong.

Comment: Can you share the code where you're using the form and expecting the error?